# How can I see what is inside the $request variable in a Slimapp php POST?

Tags: php, apache

Essentially, I am looking for help troubleshooting.  This worked last week and I've changed nothing.

I have apache running on my local machine and am using Chrome plugin REST Console to send POSTs to my own URL.  As I mentioned, last week this worked fine.  This week, I get an error that seems to say my JSON object has nulls or empty values in it.  The error message is:

```
{"error":{"text":SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 
'id' cannot be null}id was:
```

My code:

```
<?php
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
function connect_to_db() {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=moviedb','movieuser','ONVYyc5FiBPcKaK4');
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    return $conn;
}

$app = new \Slim\App;


$app->post('/movies/add', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    $id = $request->getParam('id');
    $name = $request->getParam('name');
    $description = $request->getParam('description');
    $stars = $request->getParam('stars');
    $length = $request->getParam('length');
    $image = $request->getParam('image');
    $year = $request->getParam('year');
    $rating = $request->getParam('rating');
    $director = $request->getParam('director');
    $url = $request->getParam('url');
    $sql_query = "INSERT INTO movies (id,name,description,stars,length,image,year,rating,director,url) VALUES (:id,:name,:description,:stars,:length,:image,:year,:rating,:director,:url)";
    try{
        $db = connect_to_db();
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql_query);
        $stmt->bindParam(':id',$id);
        $stmt->bindParam(':name',$name);
        $stmt->bindParam(':description',$description);
        $stmt->bindParam(':stars',$stars);
        $stmt->bindParam(':length',$length);
        $stmt->bindParam(':image',$image);
        $stmt->bindParam(':year',$year);
        $stmt->bindParam(':rating',$rating);
        $stmt->bindParam(':director',$director);
        $stmt->bindParam(':url',$url);
        $stmt->execute();
        $db = null;
        echo '{"Result":{"text":"Added"}';
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error":{"text":'.$e->getMessage().'}'.'id was: '.$id;
    }
});

$app->run();
```

and the JSON I used to test:

```
{"id":"test",
"name":"test movie",
"description":"test movie",
"stars":"test movie",
"length":"test movie",
"image":"test movie",
"year":"test movie",
"rating":"test movie",
"director":"test movie",
"url":"test movie"
}
```

What can I do to troubleshoot this?  What goes on between a POST and my apache server and then the php that might be stripping the JSON?  If the JSON is there in the $request variable, how could I see that?  What configuration might have gotten changed that would cause this to stop working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manually setting `content-type` to `application/json` did the trick in both the Android app and the REST Console.  I am still unsure why it previously worked without setting that parameter.